# If condition for ?? operator on null object

Tags: c#, .net, null

I have the following `string` list:

```
List<string> Emails = new List<string>();
```

Trying to see if it has any values, or return an empty string:

```
string Email = Emails[0] ?? "";
```

The above code throws an exception:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

But changing the `??` operator to a simple `if` statement, it works fine:

```
if (Emails.Count > 0)
    Email = Emails[0];
else
    Email = "";
```

What am I missing here? 
When the list is empty, should `Emails[0]` not be `null` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Emails[0] will try access first item of the list - that is why it throws exception

Comment: The issue here is the two pieces of code are not equivalent. In the second piece, you are correctly checking the array bounds `Emails.Count > 0` before attempting to access an array element `Emails[0]`. In the first piece, you are correctly checking if the element at index zero is null using the null coalescing operator, but you are not correctly checking the array bounds - this is the exception you get.

Comment: The list isn't null so there is no point in using `??`. The first item isn't null either - there is no first item. Using `FirstOrDefault` or an quivalent explicit check  will work. If you care about the first item though, wouldn't it be better to switch to a more appropriate container like `Queue<>`?

Comment: You are not comparing like-with-like! - `Emails.Count` and `Emails[0]` are doing 2 different things, your code will also crash with the same exception if you compare like-with-like i.e: ► `if (Emails[0] == null)`

Comment: @KobyDouek what are you trying to do? Why not a Queue, or a simple `foreach` over the `IEnumerable<>T` list? Returning an empty string means you don't know whether the list was empty or the first item was an empty string. You could end up missing entries this way

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to take the first instance of a list, if it exists. Later I am using the list for other things. Thanks for your comment, appreciate it.

Comment: @KobyDouek It does say in the tool-tip of the downvote icon `Does not show research effort`, my guess is that checking the documentation of `List<T>.Count` and a quick look-up on the `Index out of Range` error could have answered your question `When the list is empty, should Emails[0] not be null`?

Comment: @KobyDouek I asked what are *you* trying to do, not what the code does. Do you really want to discard all emails if the first entry is empty? Because that's what the code shows. `emails.Where(email=>!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(email)).FirstOrDefault()` would make more sense. If you want to use one main recipient and the rest for CC, checking the length would be easier

Comment: @Fran I actually did search this problem but completely missed the fact that I am refereing to a place in a list which does not exist. It's not that trivial finding a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest to change it to:

```
string Email = Emails.FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
```

If your list is empty, `Emails[0]` is not null, it just doesn't exist.

**Edit**:  that works for strings and ref types, if you do have a value type, for example int, you will get default(int) that is 0 as result of FirstOrDefault of empty collection

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` Does not exist on `Emails`

Comment: @Koby It is an extension method on `Enumerable` found in `using System.Linq;` namespace.

Comment: @Maksim Quick off the mark with the answer! If you want to increase the quality of the answer, provide an explanation about the two pieces of code the OP provided and where the problem was, then how your solution helps him. This will add value to an future readers of this question.

Comment: If the OP cares about the first item, why not switch to a `Queue<>`? Returning an empty string actually hides what happened - was the list empty or did it contain an empty string? Are there *other* non-empty values perhaps?

Comment: If OP need to know when first item was actually `null` - this solution will overwrite it with empty string

Comment: I think this is the best solution, but you might add info, that this doesn't work on value types

Comment: @Pikoh - no. Check in the answer solution with `if.. else` statement

Comment: @Pikoh the OP's code may do that, but it may simply be a bad way to check for empty or avoid "bad nulls" with an even worse magic value.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I totally agree. But if that's what OP wants, this solution does it exactly :)

Answer (score 4):

`Emails[0]` will try access first item of the list - that is why it throws exception.

You can use "readable" `DefaultIfEmpty` method for declaring "default" value if collection is empty

```
string Email = Emails.DefaultIfEmpty("").First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string Email = Emails[0]
```

That is the problem. `??` only checks if whats on its left is `null` and acts accordingly.

You seem to have the misconception that an empty list has `null` stored at index `0`. That is most definitely not the case. These two lists are semantically very different:

```
var emptyList = new List<string>();
var someList = new List<string>() { null };
```

In your code you are trying to access the item at position zero of an empty list. This is an index out of range exception because there is no such item. The exception is thrown before the `??` operator is even evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Emails[0] will throw exception as you access element 0 that is not exist
as Maksim suggested Emails.FirstOrDefault() will return null if the list is empty which you check by ?? coalesce operator